# Fail to display any image via X11

Tags: r, x11, cairo

Recently, when I wanted to display any image via `X11`, I just see a big white window and nothing else. For example:

```
 #Running X11() or not doesn't matter
 #X11()
 #plot anything
 plot(1:10)
```

And then, I get nothing but a white windows just like I purely run `X11()`. When I use other device (`pdf()`, `png()`), I can get image after `dev.off()`.

Problem solved. It's a problem about cairo. Add`grDevices::X11.options(type="ncairo")` to `~/.Rprofile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a blank window is the correct behaviour for calling `X11()`.  Usually, you won't need to call that function, but it means that you can specify how tall/wide the plot window is before you create a plot.

If you still have a blank window after you try and plot something, then you are probably writing to a different device.

Have you opened another device (maybe with `png`, etc.) and forgotten to close it?

What does `dev.cur()` return?

A reproducible example of this:

```
png("foo.png")
x11()
dev.set(dev.list()[names(dev.list()) == "png:foo.png"])
plot(1:10)

#Make sure you call this afterwards
graphics.off()
```

Comment: Thank you. Your help have helped me to find that it's a bug about cairo. I have use X11.options(type="ncairo") to solve the problem.